# Class keeps repeating itself, despite having a 'return' statement for the next class

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, while-loop, try-catch

This is my first attempt at learning a programming language... Ok, so I'm working on exercise 45 of Learn Python the Hard Way, trying to create a text-based game. I've had a few roadblocks thus far, but this one is by far the most frustrating. I have borrowed (and tweaked) the author's code from a previous exercise, but that only allowed the use of one function, enter(), per class, where I want to use up to five. To do this, I tried to implement a try/exception tree that would run additional functions if they were there, and if not, move on to the next classs.

What happens is, my first class, IntroScreen(), runs fine, it points to Bedroom() fine, and then Bedroom repeats itself over and over again, even though I have a command to return to Kitchen(), the next class.

I have added a #comment# in the code below to show where I think it's messing up. If you know how to fix this, please help; or, even better, if you have a better way of doing this then that would be fantastic. I've been told that this looks kinda screwy.

I can provide my entire code if that helps; please, someone help me out!

```
   class Map(Scene):

     scenes = {
        'introscreen': IntroScreen(),
        'bedroom': Bedroom(),
        'kitchen': Kitchen(),
        'fourth': Fourth()
        }

    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene

    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        return Map.scenes.get(scene_name)

    def opening_scene(self):
        # i think this is the part that's screwing up!!!
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)

class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        self.scene_map = scene_map

    def play(self):
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()

        while True:
            print "----------"
            try:
                next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()

            except:

                try:
                    next_scene_no2 = current_scene.second()

                except:

                    try:
                        next_scene_no3 = current_scene.third()

                    except:

                        try: 
                            next_scene_no4 = current_scene.fourth()

                        except:

                            try:    
                                next_scene_no5 = current_scene.fifth()

                            except:
                                break

            current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)
```

Comment: There is not enough context provided to assist with your problem. Try to break down the example and simplify what's happening. When you do this -- the answer may leap out to you.

Comment: What does `Bedroom.enter()` return? That's where the name of the next scene to be run comes from, if I understand the code you've shown correctly. Note that `next_scene_name` won't get set if there's an exception that sends you into your `try`/`except` chain (which seems rather silly, though without knowing why you've written it I can't suggest an alternative).

Comment: If either of you would like to take a look at the entire code, here it is: http://pastebin.com/bavLEBRS... I would tend to agree that the try/except chain is silly, but I didn't know another way to set it up.

Comment: What are you trying to aceieve with your try/except nestings ? There is almost certainly a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

In your Map class, are you wanting to create a new instance of Map?

```
def next_scene(self, scene_name):
    return Map.scenes.get(scene_name)  <----

def opening_scene(self):
    # i think this is the part that's screwing up!!!
    return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)
```

When debugging, use print statements as an easy way to see what is happening, e.g.

```
def next_scene(self, scene_name):
    tmp_scene = Map.scenes.get(scene_name)
    print('in Map:next_scene - tmp_scene = ', tmp_scene)
    return tmp_scene
```